# Null pointer exception for interface instance

Tags: android, interface

Iam doing a news app.But,I am encountering null pointer exception when I implement OnSendResultInterface in ListFragment.Below is my List fragment.The method is sendResult.

```
    public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener,
    OnSendResultInterface {
private ListView mListview;
private OnItemPressListener mItempressed;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    .......
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    ..........
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    if (null != mItempressed) {
        mItempressed.OnItemPress(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void sendResult(List<Entry> result) {
Log.v("result", "result" + result);
    RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(getActivity(), result);
    mListview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

This is my DownloadXmlTask.In this class Iam initializing the interface and declaring the method.

```
    public class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Entry>> {
private OnSendResultInterface mSendResult;<---this is the listener

@Override
protected List<Entry> doInBackground(String... urls) {
.......
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Entry> result) {
    if (null != result)
        mSendResult.sendResult(result);  <----null pointer exception shown here.

}

public List<Entry> downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
    ..........
}
}
```

Comment: Could you re-arrange your code for the listener portion as it's a bit distorted. Also, check whether your `mListview` is initialized when the method `sendResult` is fired.

Comment: thats it.I have done nothing extra

Answer (score 0):

mSendResult variable is not initialized anywhere.